# Сокетный сервер на Си закрывает соединение

Tags: c, сокет

Всем привет! Так как с Си я совсем незнаком, а для эмуляции некоторого процесса срочно необходим сокетный сервер на этом самом Си, то обращаюсь к вам за помощью:
Есть такой код сервера (честно найденный на просторах интернета):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int  n;

    /* First call to socket() function */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
    {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        return 1;
    }
    /* Initialize socket structure */
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 5001;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    /* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
                          sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
         perror("ERROR on binding");
         return 1;
    }
    /* Now start listening for the clients, here 
     * process will go in sleep mode and will wait 
     * for the incoming connection
     */
    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    while (1) 
    {
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0)
        {
            perror("ERROR on accept");
            return 1;
        }
        /* Create child process */
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
        {
            perror("ERROR on fork");
            return 1;
        }
        if (pid == 0)  
        {
            /* This is the client process */
            //printf("Close socket connection...\n");
            close(sockfd);
            doprocessing(newsockfd);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            close(newsockfd);
        }
    } /* end of while */
}

int doprocessing (int sock)
{
    int n;
    char buffer[256];

    bzero(buffer,256);

    n = read(sock,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR reading from socket");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
    n = write(sock, "I got your message",18);
    printf("Sending message\n");
    if (n < 0) 
    {
        perror("ERROR writing to socket");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Взаимодействую с ним из флеша. Однако когда посылаю что-нибудь на сервер, он отвечает и закрывает соединение. Если пытаюсь закомментировать строку close(sockfd); то соединение остается живым, но уже не принимает сообщений.
Помогите пожалуйста поправить, чтобы не отключало клиента и продолжало слушать его сообщения.

Comment: если Вам нужен сервер для тестов, который бы читал запросы и мог генерировать простые ответы, то может просто использовать netcat? (он доступен до линуксом). В данном случае, открываете консоль и пишете

    nc -l 5001

и можно подключаться.
Запросы будут видны в консоли. Тут же можно и ответы клиенту вписать.

Comment: А этот пример так и написан.

А Вам что от сервера нужно? Какой у Вас *прикладной* (т.е. на уровне "application") протокол обмена?

--

Кстати, `close(sockfd)` в потомке никак не должен влиять на связь (может Вы хотели скахать, что играетесь с `close(newsockfd);` в родителе?).

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, то обмениваюсь я наборами байтов(ByteArray в ActionScript3). Тем не менее, играюсь я именно с close в потомке...

Comment: @ToRcH565 о да, WSA и подобное:) а fork не смущает? Это Вам не виндовс, а Линукс.

Comment: @SoWa, так какого поведения сервера Вы хотите добиться?

--

Кстати, насчет close в потомке. Я взял, да и проверил. **Естественно не влияет. Никикак** (на этом уровне обзора) **не влияет**.

Comment: незнаком с си и линухами, а код оч на базовый пример по wsa похож, отсюда и предположение)

Comment: @ToRcH565, а откуда, по Вашему, в винде взялись сокеты?

Из Unix (если не путаю, впервые такой API появился в BSD). Поэтому и все базовые примеры похожи.

Comment: @avp хотелось добиться, чтобы сервер не закрывал соединение, и мог продолжать принимать сообщения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ по коду. В принципе так и должно быть. Посмотрите в свою функцию `doprocessing` - она получает одно сообщение, отправляет ответ и выходит. Где и закрывает соединение.

Вот навскидку переделка

```
int doprocessing (int sock)
{
    int n;
    char buffer[256];
while (1) {   // 1 добавленная строка
    bzero(buffer,256);

    n = read(sock,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR reading from socket");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
    n = write(sock, "I got your message",18);
    printf("Sending message\n");
    if (n < 0) 
    {
        perror("ERROR writing to socket");
        return 0;
    }
} // вторая добавленная строка
}
```

Comment: поправте вызов процедуры еще, она должна быть потоком иначе новым подключениям будет игнор.

Comment: какие потоки? там форк. там все будет работать.

Comment: Если несложно обьясните в каком месте создается еще поток? ваш код зависнет на данной процедуре если небыло доп потока(выхода то нет из нее, главная функция продолжатся как будет?)

зы. как выше говорил ни с си ни с линухами незнаком.

Comment: кажется понял, вопрос отпал)

Comment: потока нет. Почитайте о [fork](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/linux_parallel/node7.html) и наконец начните учить нормальную ось.
Замечу, что в винде (по крайней мере в официальном api) аналога fork нет.

Comment: То что надо, спасибо большое!